# Win32 DrawText stange aligment issue

Tags: c++, winapi, drawtext

Using Win7 x64 c++ with MSVC2010 pro.

I have noticed a really strange bug when using the Win32 DrawText to draw some text for a custom control. Its a pretty standard thing to do I'm sure. I did see a post about something similar and the solution was to use one the TextOut calls, but that doesn't resolve my issue.

I've subclass the "Static" control using the SetWindowSubClass and I'm hanlding the wm_paint message as:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        RECT rect;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;

        HDC hdc = BeginPain(hWnd,&ps);

        // Create a back buffer to draw to
        HDC hdcBack = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        GetClientRect(hWnd,&rect);
        HBITMAP hbmBackbuffer= CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,rect.right,rect.bottom);

        size_t iLength = 0;
        StringCchLength(LCDText,240,&Length);

        SelectObject(hdcBack,hbmBackbuffer);

        // Draw a black background to clear previous text
        SelectObject(hdcBack,GetSysColour(1)); // Black
        Rectangle(hdcBack,rect.left,rect.top,rect.right,rect.bottom);

        // Set the font, tranparency and text colour
        SelectObject(hdcBack,LCDFont);
        SetBkMode(hdcBack,TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(hdcBack,0x0000ff00);
        DrawText(hdcBack,LCDText,(int)iLength,&rect,DT_LEFT);

        // display
        BitBlt(hdc,0,0,rect.right,rect.bottom,hdcBack,0,0,SRCCOPY);

        // cleanup
        DeleteObject(hbmBackbuffer);
        DeleteDC(hdcBack);

        EndPaint(hWnd,&ps);

        break;
    }
```

This actually works very well. The problem is that the the 'label' can display 3 lines of 40 chararcters, and after the 27 character of each line the next chars to the end of that line are 1 or 2 pixels higher up the screen. It's not immediately apparent but once you notice it then it kindof draws your attention.

Does anyone have any ideas or experience with this?

ps - I typed the code in manually into the forum so there may be some silly typos but the real code does work properly apart the alignment issue.

Regards
Dave.

Comment: Never experienced anything like.  Does it happen when you create a new font calling CreateFont() and SelectObject() that to the hdcBack before calling DrawText?

Comment: After some more testing, it actually appears to be 'vertical tear' in the placement of the text within the hWnd rect. I've tried not using a double buffer method - Drawtext straight to the original hdc, and ive also tried different fonts and sizes. The 'vertical tear' of a pixel or two is always in the same place ( in pixel count from the left, not the character count ) regardless of the text. Changing the text to opaque doesnt make any difference, although note the text bound rect has a straight bottom edge even though the text itself is lifted by a few pixels. Very strange.

Comment: After some more testing, if i create the font using:
    CreateFont(....GM_COMPATIBLE,GM_COMPATIBLE...)

then you cant see the 'shear',

but using...
    CreateFont(...GM_ADVANCED,GM_ADVANCED....)

then you can see the verical shift when using opaque text and backgrounds.

Comment: More playing...
Making the static control bigger in height moves the effect further left :/

Comment: Wow, this only happens in your custom controls right?  It doesn't happen for the MainWindow?  If you can, can you please try my LOGFONT suggestion @ http://pastebin.com/0Y4Uc3JS

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of this? Seems very weird.

Comment: well i never!! it works ok when using your method. I'll change the code to suit. Thank you for your suggestion. I'm stuck for words.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: For the sake of showing the effect a pic is here:
[link](http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah45/dave1camp1/Untitled_zps79855b37.jpg)

I've put the outline of a red box under the text to show the misalignment. Using the the logfont method as ChubosaurusSoftware suggested works ok.